# How to Find the Full Size (In Pixels) For a C1FlexGrid Control?

Tags: c#, winforms, c1flexgrid

I have a C1FlexGrid control that is filled with a number of rows and columns.

How can I ask the control what is the "Full Size" for it (in pixels)?

By Full Size I mean, the .Size property value that I should set it with,
so all of its cells will be displayed, without needing any scrollbars/scrolling by the user.

Comment: It looks like `myC1FlexGrid.Height` should work... as well as .Size and .Width...
http://prerelease.componentone.com/help/WinForms/WinForms.Flexgrid.pdf

Comment: Does GetPreferredSize() work?

Comment: **Austin:** The .Height property tells me what is the current height, not what is the full/optimal height for the control.. **adv12:** GetPreferredSize() returns a Size struct, but also asks for a Size struct as a parameter.. (why is it asking one? the MSDN page for this method is not very clear regarding this parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I don't know if they created a special property for it,
but I managed to do it by asking the control for the `.Bottom` of the last row, and the `.Right` of the last column:

```
C1FG.Height =C1FG.Rows[C1FG.Rows.Count-1].Bottom+2;
C1FG.Width  =C1FG.Cols[C1FG.Cols.Count-1].Right +2;
```

And it works.